# Get time until specific point in time

Tags: java, date, timer, calendar

I want to return the time in `millisecond` of the time until `20:00` on the next upcoming `Wednesday` or `20:00` on the next upcoming `Saturday`, depending on which is closest. I just don't know how to get the time in `millisecond` of each of these times.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Your issues have been handled many times already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();                  //Get current Date time
LocalDateTime nextSaturday = now                          //Get date time
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)) //of next SATURDAY
        .with(LocalTime.of(20, 0));                       //at 20:00   

//Now you can use until with ChronoUnit.MILLIS to get millisecond betwenn the two dates
long millSeconds = now.until(nextSaturday, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
//or             = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(now, nextSaturday);

System.out.println(now);          //2018-07-05T16:54:54.585789200
System.out.println(nextSaturday); //2018-07-07T20:00
System.out.println(millSeconds);  //183905414
```

---

With zone time you can use :

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));//Or any zone time
ZonedDateTime nextSaturday = now
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY))
        .with(LocalTime.of(20, 0));
long millSeconds = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(now, nextSaturday);

System.out.println(now);           //2018-07-05T18:25:10.377511100+02:00[Europe/Paris]
System.out.println(nextSaturday);  //2018-07-07T20:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]
System.out.println(millSeconds);   //178489622
```

---

To check which is close `Wednesday` or `Saturday` you can use :

```
LocalDate saturday = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY));
LocalDate wednesday = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY));

long result;
if(saturday.isBefore(wednesday)){
    result = getMillSecond(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY);
}
result = getMillSecond(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY);
```

Or as @Andreas suggest in comment you can use :

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
DayOfWeek day = EnumSet.range(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)
        .contains(now.getDayOfWeek()) ? DayOfWeek.SATURDAY : DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;
long result = getMillSecond(day);
```

and you can put one of the previous code in a method and call it based on the condition above :

```
public static long getMillSecond(DayOfWeek day){
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));//Or any zone time
    ZonedDateTime nextSaturday = now
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(day))
            .with(LocalTime.of(20, 0));
    return ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(now, nextSaturday);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't account for Daylight Savings Time. Still +1

Comment: Thank you @Andreas what about this solution https://ideone.com/jeZGaa, is that what you mean?

Comment: More like this: https://ideone.com/1YwYHi --- It sets time to 8 PM, not 8:00:15.685 PM, and it ensures that start and end times are in the same time zone, rather than changing the time zone of only the end time.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas I appreciate your help

Comment: "If you care about zone time" -> You should ALWAYS care about that before it bites you in the ass.

Comment: I agree @SebastiaanvandenBroek I removed that part *If you care* ;)

Comment: For choosing between Wednesday and Saturday, you can also do: `DayOfWeek day = (EnumSet.range(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY).contains(now.getDayOfWeek()) ? DayOfWeek.SATURDAY : DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY);`

Comment: Intelligent solution @Andreas thank you so much

Comment: I just did if millisUntilWednesday < millisUntilSaturday to check which is closer.

Comment: @oopsie correct that also solve your problem `if(getMillSecond(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY) < getMillSecond(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)){` I find it smart idea also ;)